# How can I perform a package specific security check

Tags: java, securitymanager

I would like to invoke my SecurityManager checkPackageAccess for a named package.

Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:/C:/Temp/java.policy");

System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkPackageAccess(String pkg) {
            super.checkPackageAccess(pkg);
            // do my specific stuff
        }
```

});

and my policy file

```
package.restrict.access.pkgname=true
package.access=com.mypackage
```

However the checkPackageAccess method is getting called on every method invocation. Any idea how to restrict it so it just gets called when methods in side com.mypackage are invoked?

Thanks in advance